# Filters without pipe Angular 6: overriding problem

Tags: javascript, html, angular, filter, angular6

I have 2 categories of filters: `group` and `name`. How can I modify this code because they are not working as a pipe, they are independent, and the `name` filter overrides `group` filter, and backward.

.ts

```
 changeGroup(event) {
   const group = event.target.value;
   const index = this.groupValue.indexOf(group);

   if (index > -1) {
     this.groupValue.splice(index, 1);
   } else {
     this.groupValue.push(group);
   }

   this.transform(this.usersList, 'group', this.groupValue)

   if (this.groupValue.length == 0) {
     this.transform(this.usersList, '', this.groupValue)
   }
 }

 changeUser(event) {
   const user = event.target.value;
   const index = this.userValue.indexOf(user);

   if (index > -1) {
     this.userValue.splice(index, 1);
   } else {
     this.userValue.push(user);
   }

   this.transform(this.usersList, 'name', this.userValue)

   if (this.userValue.length == 0) {
     this.transform(this.usersList, '', this.userValue)
   }
 }

 transform(items: any[], field: string, value: string[]): any[] {
   if (!items) {
     return [];
   }
   if (!field || !value || value.length <= 0) {
     return items
   }

   this.newArray = items.filter(singleItem => {
     return (singleItem != null && singleItem[field] != null && singleItem[field] != undefined && value.indexOf(singleItem[field]) >= 0);
   });

   return this.newArray
 }
```

.html

```
    <ng-container *ngFor="let group of groups">
        <label class="btn btn-filter" id="bttns">
        <input type="checkbox" name="customersGroupFilter" autoComplete="off" [value]="group" (change)="changeGroup($event)">
        {{ group }}
      </label>&nbsp;
    </ng-container>

    <br>

    <ng-container *ngFor="let user of users">
        <label class="btn btn-filter" id="bttns">
        <input type="checkbox" name="customersUserFilter" autoComplete="off" [value]="user" (change)="changeUser($event)">
        {{ user }}
      </label>&nbsp;
    </ng-container>

    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Group</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let user of newArray">
          <td>{{user.name}}</td>
          <td>{{user.group}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

[Here is a working snippet](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cnazod)

Thank you for your time!

Comment: First of all, you're not even using the functionality as a `pipe`. Secondly, I don't see them overriding anything, they both work.

Comment: That's why I am asking, I don't know how to make them work as a pipe. Second of all, they do override. If you check `tim` and then `a`, `a` will immediately override `tim`, I am expecting a `[]` result, because `tim` does not belong to group `a`. Don't be rude if you can't answer, thank you.

Comment: @Tenzolinho why are you talking about pipe ? What's your idea ? If you want to know how to create a pipe, check the documentation : https://angular.io/guide/pipes#custom-pipes You must create a class decorated by `pipe` implements `PipeTransform` and override `transform` method. But I don't see why you need pipe in your case.

Comment: Be glad you didn't make pipes, as [this kind of pipes are discouraged](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe). Without reading your code, I suggest you keep it that way (i.e. in your component), and don't make a pipe out of it.

Comment: I had pipes before, but I read they are not good, so I changed and moved the `transform` function inside component. My question is what am I doing wrong, how can I modify this code to work as a pipe. Is this even possible?

Comment: @Tenzolinho you don't your code "to work as a pipe". You need to change your code inside your component, your logic inside your component is not good at the moment.

Comment: I have made some changes, `https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-regyev?file=src/app/app.component.ts` can you check is this what you were looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check the **app.component.ts** below no need of extra transforming login. just add a **get** property reader "**filteredArray**" in this file, You can use following approach without using pipe.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    name: string;

    groups = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    users = ['john', 'mike', 'doe', 'tim']

    usersList = [
        { 'name': 'john', 'group': 'a' },
        { 'name': 'mike', 'group': 'a' },
        { 'name': 'doe', 'group': 'b' },
        { 'name': 'tim', 'group': 'c' }]
    groupValue: string[] = []
    userValue: string[] = []

    newArray = []

    ngOnInit() {
        this.newArray = this.usersList.slice()
    }

    changeGroup(event) {
        const group = event.target.value;
        const index = this.groupValue.indexOf(group);

        if (index > -1) {
            this.groupValue.splice(index, 1);
        } else {
            this.groupValue.push(group);
        }
    }

    changeUser(event) {
        const user = event.target.value;
        const index = this.userValue.indexOf(user);

        if (index > -1) {
            this.userValue.splice(index, 1);
        } else {
            this.userValue.push(user);
        }
    }

    get filteredArray() {
        let arrayData = [];
        if (this.groupValue.length === 0 && this.userValue.length === 0) {
            return this.usersList;
        }

        return this.usersList.filter((user) => {

            return (this.userValue.length > 0 ? this.userValue.indexOf(user.name) !== -1 : true)
                && (this.groupValue.length > 0 ? this.groupValue.indexOf(user.group) !== -1 : true);
        })
    }
}
```

corresponding app.component.html code below.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let group of groups">
    <label class="btn btn-filter" id="bttns">
        <input type="checkbox" name="customersGroupFilter" autoComplete="off" [value]="group" (change)="changeGroup($event)">
        {{ group }}
    </label>&nbsp;
</ng-container>

<br>

<ng-container *ngFor="let user of users">
    <label class="btn btn-filter" id="bttns">
        <input type="checkbox" name="customersUserFilter" autoComplete="off" [value]="user" (change)="changeUser($event)">
        {{ user }}
    </label>&nbsp;
</ng-container>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Group</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let user of filteredArray">
            <td>{{user.name}}</td>
            <td>{{user.group}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

for Reference added a inline screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Brilliant idea. Thank you a million times!

Comment: Most Welcome @Tenzolinho

Answer (score 1):

You were creating `new array` either with `group` or `users`.

So I have made some changes in your code by adding both array condition on both of the events.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-regyev?file=src/app/app.component.ts

```
this.transform(this.usersList, 'group', this.groupValue);
this.transform(this.newArray, 'name', this.userValue);

if (this.groupValue.length == 0) {
  this.transform(this.usersList, '', this.groupValue);
  this.transform(this.newArray, '', this.userValue);
}
```

Comment: @Florian, what have you checked?

Comment: check 'a' and uncheck it. See RANJIT answer, his code is pretty good.

Comment: It's my fault with check and uncheck, my code was bad. But you did what I've asked, so I upvoted your answer. Ranjit fixed this check/uncheck bug so I accepted his answer. Thannk you, anyway!

Comment: Thanks Tenzolinho, @Florian, anyways updated the code and optimized it.